# Would calling .size() on every entry be a performance issue for Hazelcast?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hazelcast

I have an experimental `EntryListener` on a Hazelcast `Map` that calls `.size()` on every entry.

I want to know if this is a bad idea and if it could be a performance issue as it is a cluster wide operation.

Currently I can't see any performance degradation for 5-10k elements and 2 nodes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad idea. Your EntryListener will be called by Hazelcast's internal threads. And by calling map.size() you are doing a pretty expensive operation and blocking the thread.
Calling any distributed operation inside Hazelcast's threads are not recommended. You should receive the event and call map.size on your own thread. This can be done by submitting a runnable to an ExecutorService maintained by you. Note that here I mean j.u.c.ExecutorService not the Hazelcast's implementation of Distributed ES.

Comment: I failed to mention that I am calling `.size()` in my own thread. So given that do you see any other problems ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if your application does require to call size, then it is ok. Otherwise yes size() is an expensive operation. It performs on all nodes and returns the total sum. Better not to have it if possible. If you are receiving the events, why dont you keep track the size yourself? Basically on add event you'll increase the size and on remove decrease.

Comment: Agreed this might work, I didn't want to keep it myself since its extra work, but it could be better. Currently it performs perfectly even with the call to size btw.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Map implementation in HazelCast. But one general guideline is, if a container is maintaining a separate variable (namely size as we have in many classes of java.util.collection library) to count the elements added in it, then there won't be any problem in performance degrade. But if a container is iterating over the added elements to count and returns the size, there may be a significant performance degradation when the container has considerably huge no. of elements in it. May be you can look into the Map implementation of HazelCast and decide it yourself.

Comment: I'm referring generally to the fact that the map is distributed across several nodes.